# remove unwanted space and commas in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I want to remove all unnecessary spaces and commas from the start/end of the string.

eg; , 11,22,33 , should become 11,22,33

I tried this,

```
var str=",22,33,44,55,";
var splitted = str.split(",");
alert(splitted[0]);
```

But shows empty spaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
var str=",22,33,44,55,";
str.replace(/^[\s,]+|[\s,]+$/g, '').split(",");
```